# Apply MVC Master page to aspx page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, master-pages

Currently am working in MVC project . And I have one aspx page for display application errors.

Now i want to attach the MVC project master-page(`layout.cshtml`) to my `aspx`(error)page .

Is it possible ? if possible then how can do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly have a Razor Layout with WebForms Views, or a WebForms Master with Razor Views. While the concepts are similar, layouts are not masters and the concepts aren't exactly interchangeable.

look Scott Hansleman blog . He had one idea .

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx